# .eps logo disappears when I export artwork

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am creating a print advert artwork for a magazine on illustrator cs6. However, I'm having problems with one .eps logo on the artwork which disappears once I export the artwork as a jpeg. What could be causing this particular logo not to show once I export the artwork as a jpeg, yet the 2 others are showing?

Comment: If you link the logos: have you tried to embed the logo to the artwork before exporting? Can you check that the logo file is placed where Illustrator expects it to be?

Answer (score 1):

This might be an overprinting issue. Select the logo, go to the Attributes window, and make sure that the Overprint Fill and the Overprint Stroke boxes are not checked.

Comment: Or could have the **Object>Attributes** of the object with 'non-printing' selected